# Slave error (handler error HA_ERR_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT) and its impact

Tags: mysql, replication

Recently I noticed below error in slave server errorlogs in Master Slave replication. Even there is no issue in replication and slave is on time as per master. Actually I executed some heavy reporting queries on slave and inserted their results in temp/dummy (not temporary table) table. I need community help to clear my below 2 queries. I will be very thankful if anyone help me in this.

```
[ERROR] Slave SQL: Could not execute Update_rows event on table DBname.tablename; Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction,

Error_code: 1205; handler error HA_ERR_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT; the event's master log mysql-bin.******, end_log_pos *******, Error_code: 1205
```

1. As per my understanding this error occur when I was fetching report (fetching from production tables and inserting in dummy table) because mysql could not get lock and as  lock will be available for mysql the update statement will be executed successfully means my data will be up to date on slave.
2. As we know that select statement does not lock the table, so it will be happen because I was simultanously inserting data into another table along with fetching data from production table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will be very thankful if any replication master draw some attention on this query.

Answer (score 5):

Running a query on the slave does set implicit locks on the underlying tables for as long as the query runs. Concurrent queries coming from the master had to be put on hold in the mean time. As your query presumably lasted for longer than (or close to) [`innodb_lock_wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout), replication timed out.

When this happens, all you need to do is restarting replication with a simple `START SLAVE;`.

To avoid the issue altogether, you can explicitely pause replication ([`STOP SLAVE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-administration-pausing.html)) before running your reporting queries, then resume replication after you are done.

As a workaround, you could also increase [`slave_transaction_retries`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html).

Comment: Actually here I don't have any issue so no need to stop and start slave. I want to clear just my doubts, which have been cleared from some other blogs as it was as my expectations.